# reactive form .reset() not clearing the validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using a simple reactive form in Angular6.

```
this.phoneForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  oldMac: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('')
  ])),
  newMac: ['', Validators.required],
  newModel: ['', [Validators.required]],
  targetCluster: ['', [Validators.required]],
  ownerUser: ['', [Validators.required]]
}, { updateOn: 'blur' });
```

To reset I am using `this.phoneForm.reset();`, it is clearing the form but does not clear the validators, my form is showing as invalid.

Please help

EDIT: I forget to add that I am using angular-material input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216330/angular-5-formgroup-reset-doesnt-reset-validators?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @raju https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300628/angular-reactive-forms-set-and-clear-validators

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following:

```
this.phoneForm.clearValidators();
this.phoneForm.updateValueAndValidity();  
this.phoneForm.reset();
```

From the docs:

> [`clearValidators()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#clearvalidators)
>
> Empties out the sync validator list.
>
> [`updateValueAndValidity()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity)
>
> Recalculates the value and validation status of the control.

Comment: This does not have any effect, all input fields after submit are still red

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4190
Reset simply clears the content of the form triggering the validation to fail as no values are provided. 
In order to essentialy reset to a base state the forms should be marked as pristine or untouched.

```
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
      let control = this.form.controls[key];
      control.reset(); // clear control's contents.

      // resets the control the before user interaction state
      control.markAsPristine(); 

      // As raju stated this will not only remove errors but also remove all validators.
      control.setErrors(null); 
    });
```

Comment: This removes all the validators also.

Comment: Thanks Raju, that's news to me. I didn't know that validators could be cleared like that.